# R package h5r configure: error: Can't find HDF5

Tags: 16.04, package-management, r

I am trying to install the [R-pbh-5](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/R-pbh5) package for R, which requires [h5r](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/h5r/). When I try to install `h5r` with `install_version("h5r", "1.4.7")`, I receive the following error:

```
[...]
checking for library containing inflate... -lz
checking for library containing H5open... no
configure: error: Can't find HDF5
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘h5r’
```

I searched the Ubuntu package index for HDF5 and installed the libraries `libhdf5-10`, `libhdf5-dev`, `hdf5-tools`, and `pbh5tools`. It seems to be correctly installed as well:

```
$ whereis hdf5
hdf5: /usr/include/hdf5
```

I just spent the last hours googling, but I can't figure out what I'm missing here. Any advice?

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2018-02-12 r74246)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/R/3.5.0/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/3.5.0/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.17    Rhdf5lib_1.1.5
```

**Update 1:**

Following the suggestions in the comments, I managed to get one step further. When I run:

```
R CMD INSTALL h5r_1.4.7.tar.gz --configure-vars="LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial'"
```

I now receive the following error:

```
-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/
checking for library containing inflate... -lz
checking for library containing H5open... -lhdf5
checking for sufficiently new HDF5... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c h5_debug.c -o h5_debug.o
h5_debug.c:4:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'h5_debug.o' failed
make: *** [h5_debug.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘h5r’
```

Comment: There are some historic issues with Debian (and derivatives) packaging the HDF5 headers / libraries in a `serial` subdirectory - I wonder if that's the issue here? Perhaps there's a way around it by passing appropriate `--configure-vars` to the build process?

Comment: I am not so familiar with custom build commands. Could you help me out and formulate the appropriate option which would point to the `hdf libs`?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not either - there's some information [here](https://github.com/mannau/h5) based on which I'd try something like `R CMD INSTALL <whatever> --configure-vars='LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/'`

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install hdf5-helpers`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Installing `hdf5-helpers` did not change anything, but @steeldriver was pointing me in the right direction. I updated the question.

Comment: You will likely need to do the same for the include path: not sure if multiple `--configure-vars` are supported or if you need to do them all in a single invocation i.e. `--configure-vars='CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/`

Comment: I am already doing that (changing CPPFLAGS to CFLAGS did not change anything).

Comment: Hmm... then I'm just about out of ideas - I've seen references online that suggest using `INCLUDE_DIR` and `LIB_DIR` in place of the generic `CFLAGS` / `LDFLAGS` - maybe try those?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this produces the same output as no flags at all. It's weird that `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` brings me past the checks for HDF, but then the compilation fails because hdf5.h apparently can't be found. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, although in slightly messy way. I used `sudo cp -rs /usr/include/hdf5/serial/* /usr/share/R/include` to create links to all the hdf5 files within the `R/include` folder, which is included in the build by default.